# what trick do you use to have minimum stress on the lens while hiking?

Tags: lens, travel, equipment-protection

My camera bag has two positions lens facing upward or downward. Most camera bags will have this position when mounted on your shoulder. I am attaching a picture of mine:

[image]

So like most camera bags, either my lens will creep down or creep up because of gravity when walking. The creep is not important when the bag is at home or in a studio or in the back of the car. While walking long distances however, this can be significant. So what trick do you use to have minimum stress on the lens?

Comment: You say "this can be significant". What in particular are you worried about?

Comment: Relevant: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/24801/9161

Answer (score 3):

Most bags/backpacks have adjustable dividers that allow you to customize the size of a space for each item. If you only leave enough space in the bag for the camera/lens combination when the lens is fully retracted, it shouldn't creep at all.

This lens has internal zoom, so it doesn't creep from gravity, but the concept is the same. Immobilize the camera/lens in your bag by giving it no room to move.

[image: Camera in bag]

Answer (score 2):

I have this bag. As Michael said you should be able to adjust the dividers and other items to give a snug fit. I don't see how it would make a difference in terms of stress whether you had the camera at the top with lens facing downwards or vice versa.
Personally I have the camera at the top because I often have a water bottle in one of the side compartments at the bottom, and this would prevent damaging the camera in the event of a leak.

Comment: You keep water inside? I prefer to keep water outside so that it is more readily accessible. The bag had pockets for that. Interestingly, just today I figured out that this bag had its own rainfly snugly tugged at the botom. After 3 years of using it!

Comment: That's the sort of thing that if you don't notice it at the start, you might never notice! The side pockets can't really accommodate larger bottles unfortunately.